# Play framework tests failing with TestsFailedException

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework activator and my tests are mostly running fake application with in memoory database (EBean ORM).

The tests are failing once to ~5 times with attached error which does not explain the reason and specific test name.
anyone familiar with this issue?

[image]

[image]

Failing test case:

```
public class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void renderTemplate() { 
        Content html = views.html.index.render("Your new application is ready.");
        assertEquals("text/html", contentType(html));
        assertTrue(contentAsString(html).contains("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem is not solvable without the code/tests in question.

Comment: this is the only test which is given in the template. I commented out all other tests.

Comment: please take a look I added another screenshot. one regular test. sometimes it fails and sometime it succeed.